# Проблема с Tkinter при сборке .exe через PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-2.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

Имеется Python 2.7. При попытке запуска .exe выводил ошибку, что можно с этим сделать?

```
D:\test\dist>Test.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Tkinter
Failed to execute script Test
```

Вот шапка файла Test.py:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
```

Comment: попробуйте изменить способ импорта import Tkinter as tk, https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1584

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что сейчас в python по умолчанию стоит *Tkinter*, но обычно он требует переустановки без которой не работает. В списках pyinstaller-а он есть, поэтому и копируется из python как полная библиотека, но так как после переустановки некоторые файлы *Tkinter* находятся в другом месте, при запуске программа не находит его. Поэтому как сказал igor попробуйте изменить способ импорта `import Tkinter as tk`, так pyinstaller примет его за установленный модуль и скопирует полностью, без проблем.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но этот способ не решает данную проблему. У меня были импортированные модули, которые я не использовал. После удаления этих строк все стало нормально. Почему так - не знаю, но моя проблема решена.